# undefined method `sranje' for #<Article:0x0000000ccab870> for scope rails 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

So how can I solve this problem...

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, -> {order :name}

  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4} 
  validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4} 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags

  scope :sranje, -> { where('published_at <= ?', Time.current) }

  def self.articles_order 
    self.all.order('published_at DESC')
  end

  # def self.sranje
  #   self.where('published_at <= ?', Time.current)
  # end
end
```

Now when ever I call the scope I get the error 
undefined method `sranje' for #

When I try the scope in the console it works i.e. (user.artilces.sranje) ...
so How can I make it work for the application, where do I chain the scope ??...

Comment: how do you call it on page?

Comment: yes, I tried chaining all over the controller, no success.. it should not show the article that will be published in future..

Comment: @GokuSan - You do have to call it on a class like `Article.sranje` .Not on the instance like `@article.sranje`

Comment: @VenkatCh donno the scope should not show the article that will be published in future, and in the console it does just that..

Comment: @GokuSan - So, please try to use as you did in console instead calling a scope method on instance. (Your question title simply says, you tried calling a scope method on instance of Article, which is incorrect.

Comment: @VenkatCh am trying to do that, like how would I call the scope in side the controller, eg. for show action, so that the app sees the article from tomorrow and not show it un till tomorrow..

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call scope with variable like

```
@article.sranje
```

if you want to do like that then add in your class

```
def sranje
 Article.where('published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now)
end
```

Comment: can you explain your problem what you want to do ?

Comment: I want the article from tomorrow not to show until tomorrow.. that is the scope for..

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved it self, don't know how.. In create action in articles controller I changed the " redirect_to ..."  and in views/articles/index I iterated with Article.sranje.each.... 
I tried that before I asked here for help, about 10 times, but 11 was a charm :) 
thanks for trying to help...

P.S I also cleaned cache if that matters....